Command line install Cygwin with specific packages and --site specification
I am replicating a Cygwin installation from one Windows 10 64-bit machine to another.  I have done this in the past, but somehow lost the recipe.  I am reconstructing it with web search and command line experimentation.
I can get the package names with cygcheck -cdn.  According to this page, I can use setup-x86_64.exe -q -P packagename1,packagename2,etc to install those packages on another machine.
However, I am behind a corporate firewall and with much work, I have gotten approval to access one mirror site.  The setup command also takes a --site option.  Can anyone point to an example for the syntax of the argument?  For example, is it always prefixed by http[s]:// or ftp[s]:// and is there anything coming after the domain name, e.g., /cygwin or the such?  I just find it surprising that there is no example at all, at least in response to my Google searches.

I'd expect the protocol specifier (e.g. http:// or ftp://) to be required either as in a direct URL or by other means.
As the word "protocol" does not appear, but URL does at...
https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.setup.cli
-s --site                         Download site URL

... the format should be a standard url, most likely with an appended site-specific path.
Compare to how the sites are listed when you runt setup.exe without any arguments (IIRC the sites are shown with paths).

Thanks. I'll give it a shot when I'm in the office.  It's too bad that one can't get a list of the site-specific paths without having to run setup.exe first.  Though I suppose that isn't much of a problem if the list is gotten from cygwin.com..  From outside the firewall, if I run the setup program from a mintty terminal and choose a download site from the setup GUI, the list doesn't show the site-specific path. After clicking Next,, however, the site-specific path shows up in one of the many messages in the terminal, e.g., path /cygwin/

Might also be it appends the site-local path by auto-magic forces. (i.e. inside setup.exe)

It is the end of the working day and I gave the solution a try.  Before trying the method of command-line installing prespecified packages (described in the posted question), I first tried to uninstall all packages in the target computer. It seems to be an extremely slow process, so I will let it run overnight and hope that corporate processes don't clobber the uninstall.  But that was my original plan, to get rid of the rather bloated installation on the target machine and replicate a more streamline installation of Cygwin.

Well the uninstall finished rather abruptly.  Not everything got uninstalled.  The uninstall was done using the setup GUI.  X-windows seems to be gone but mintty and bash still work.  Perusing the "Full" view of packages shows some packages are still present, e.g., "_autorebase", "alternatives", etc.  The "Up To Date" view also shows several dozen packages, as does the "Picked" view.  I think it's good enough of an uninstall, and I'll look at command-line replication of the packages tomorrow.

Confirmed.  The following works: setup-x86_64.exe -s https://mirror.blah.bleh.xx/cygwin -q -P _autorebase,Package1,Package2,...,PackageN.  The cygwin component of the path is probably site-specific.
